# What am i missing from jquery function in order to add value into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add some content into a textarea after the user has clicked on the "Add" button but nothing is happening. Is there anything I am missing?

Below is the jquery code which adds the selected content:

```
         $(".add").on("click", function(event) {
    console.log("clicked");
    //lets get our Question Text... 
    var theQuestion = $("td:first-child", $(this).parent()).text();
    //the row is present, let's then make sure that the proper cell gets oru data. 
    if ($('.activePlusRow').length > 0) {
        $('.activePlusRow').next('.textAreaQuestion').val(theQuestion);
        $('.activePlusRow').removeClass('activePlusRow');
    }

});

 $(".plusrow").on("click", function(event) {
    //adding a unique class for the purpose of the click. 
    $(this).addClass('activePlusRow');
});
```

Below is the textarea:

```
  $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
                   .attr('value',$this.val());


    });
```

EDIT:

You can use the application to see for yourself. Below is how to use app:

1. When you open the app click on the "Green Plus" button. A modal window will appear.
2. In the search box enter in "AAA", then click "Search".
3. Results of your search is displayed. Here is where the problem is. What I want is that when the user clicks on an "Add" button to add a "Question", it should close the modal window and add the "Question" into the top textarea, but it is not doing this.

Comment: Consider setting up a working example on http://jsfiddle.net, people will be more willing to take a look.

Comment: And use a better question title...

Comment: I realise I can't create a fiddle because first of all I have some php code and second, it actually uses 2 scripts in order for this to be accomplished. So I have set up a simple application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php) where you can see how to works and hopefully you can look at the view source. In question I will explain how to use app.

Comment: @user1421767 if you can't create a simple example (see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) to illustrate your question how do you expect others to easily replicate and identify the issue? Sure it's possible, but it takes a lot more time and effort for someone to trawl through your code and not everyone is willing to invest so much in one question, especially when the level of effort is one-sided.

Comment: @ShawnChin I have created a simple example, it is just that I couldn't do it in Jsfiddle

Comment: using $questionText.html($this.val()) ?

Comment: @user1421767 sorry. I misunderstood. My bad.

Comment: @chumkiu Where do I place this code $questionText.html($this.val())?

Comment: @user1421767 after $questionText declaration (and you canerase  .attr('value',$this.val());

Comment: @chumkiu I need .attr('value',$this.val());. without value then i have a feature which wouldn't work without it

Answer (score 0):

Textareas unlike inputs don't use the value attribute to store there data, which is probably why attr('value', 'bla') is failing.

I believe the .val() method will automatically take this in to account and thus work anyway.

Try somthing like:

```
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]").val($this.val());
```

---

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code but this didn't work. I actually need the 'value' part inside the code because in my application if you type in content in the text area and click on the "Add Question" button, then it adds the content within a table row below. So I need the 'value' in the .val()